# Twitter 4j with Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, twitter4j

First time poster, but I'm really stuck. 
I'm working on a little project and I'm trying to send out a tweet using a netbeans project. I'm using twitter4j and it seems like things have recently changed to where you have to use their OAuth function.  I've created an application on twitter and tried some code but I keep getting this error:Exception in thread "main" connect timed outRelevant discussions can be on the Internet at:

```
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=b2b52c28 or
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=1b442895 
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[b2b52c28-1b442895 b2b52c28-1b44286b], statusCode=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, featureSpecificRateLimitStatus=null, version=2.2.5}
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:200)
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:65)
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:102)
at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.post(TwitterImpl.java:1929)
at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.updateStatus(TwitterImpl.java:433)
at login.Login.start(Login.java:36)
at login.Login.main(Login.java:63)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:75)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:388)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:483)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:213)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:300)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:316)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:992)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:928)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:846)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1087)
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:158)
... 6 more
Java Result: 1
```

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. Below is the code I've tried.

```
package login;

import java.io.IOException;

import twitter4j.ResponseList;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;

public class Login {

    private final static String CONSUMER_KEY = "******";
    private final static String CONSUMER_KEY_SECRET =
     "******";

    public void start() throws TwitterException, IOException {

 Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
 twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_KEY_SECRET);

 // here's the difference
 String accessToken = getSavedAccessToken();
 String accessTokenSecret = getSavedAccessTokenSecret();
 AccessToken oathAccessToken = new AccessToken(accessToken,
  accessTokenSecret);

 twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(oathAccessToken);
 // end of difference

 twitter.updateStatus("Hi, im updating status again from Namex Tweet for Demo");

 System.out.println("\nMy Timeline:");

 // I'm reading your timeline
 ResponseList list = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
/* for (Status each : list) {

     System.out.println("Sent by: @" + each.getUser().getScreenName()
      + " - " + each.getUser().getName() + "\n" + each.getText()
      + "\n");
 }*/

    }

    private String getSavedAccessTokenSecret() {
 // consider this is method to get your previously saved Access Token
 // Secret
 return "oC8tImRFL6i8TuRkTEaIcWsF8oY4SL5iTGNkG9O0Q";
    }

    private String getSavedAccessToken() {
 // consider this is method to get your previously saved Access Token
 return "102333999-M4W1Jtp8y8QY8RH7OxGWbM5Len5xOeeTUuG7QfcY";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            new Login().start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Could I suggest an alternative route..

I have recently been messing around with twitter4j and I approached this slightly differently - I found a nice and easy way to authenticate the client using a ConfigurationBuilder object and passing this to the factory that is getting the instance of the Twitter object you need.

```
package main;

import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.TwitterStream;
import twitter4j.TwitterStreamFactory;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public class Base {

    protected Twitter twitter;
    //protected TwitterStream twitterStream;
    private ConfigurationBuilder configBuilder;

    public Base(){

        configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configBuilder.setDebugEnabled(true);        
        configBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey("[consumer key here]");
        configBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret("[consumer secret key here]");
        configBuilder.setOAuthAccessToken("[OAuthAccessToken here]");
        configBuilder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("[secret OAuthAccessToken here]");

        //use the ConfigBuilder.build() method and pass the result to the TwitterFactory
        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(configBuilder.build());
        //you can now get authenticated instance of Twitter object.
        twitter = tf.getInstance();
    }
}
```

You could then extend this class with sub classes that implement the functionality you require or just create the ConfigurationBuilder/TwitterFactory/Twitter objects elsewhere in your code.

Below I have implemented a class that creates status' and can return the Status object that holds additional information such as createdAt() and the ID etc etc.

```
package main;

import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;

public class StatusUpdater extends Base{   

    public StatusUpdater(){}

    public Status updateStatus(String statusToUpdate) throws TwitterException{
        Status status = twitter.updateStatus(statusToUpdate);
        System.out.println("statusToUpdate: " + status + ".");
        return status;
    }
}
```

Then you can use the following statement to create the status. This can be done from mbean/ejb/servlet etc.

```
     try {
            StatusUpdater statusUpdater = new StatusUpdater();
            String statusTextToSet = "test status";
            Status updatedStatus = statusUpdater.updateStatus(statusTextToSet);
            System.out.println("Created at: " + updatedStatus.getCreatedAt());
        } catch (TwitterException tex) {
            System.out.println(tex.getErrorMessage());
        }
```

More info on the configuration process [here](http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok. Have you confirmed your definitely using the correct consumer key and secret for your app? Try `twitter.verifyCredentials()` to see if you get the same error, or a more specific error.

If you're correcting to the net via a proxy, you will need to include your proxy settings to allow the connection to succeed, details can be found here http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html#HTTP%20proxy%20server

As an aside, you may want to remove you access token and secret from your post, if they're still valid then someone could login to your account with them.

Comment: Is it necessary to use a proxy server? I'm kinda new to this so I don't know all the details none of the tutorials I have looked at mentioned it. I think verifyCredentials no longer exists in the newest twitter4j (Also the access token and secret are no longer valid don't worry)

Comment: Its only necessary if you connect to the internet via a proxy server, if you don't, then you don't need them. Have you tried comiling and running the OAuth example bundled with the source code? I'm using the latest version - 2.2.5 and verifyCredentials() is definitely still there.

Comment: You're right verifyCredentials() still exists.  What part of my code are you suggesting to replace this with?

Comment: Ok so I know get this error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid access token format.
 at twitter4j.auth.AccessToken.<init>(AccessToken.java:50)
 at login.Login.start(Login.java:25)
 at login.Login.main(Login.java:58)
Java Result: 1     But, the access token was taken directly from the twitter website...

Comment: This is a different token from the one you included in the code above?

Comment: haha I created a whole new app and have been using that. The previously token was actually just from a tutorial

Comment: Well maybe try regenerating your tokens from the application setup page on Twitter and see if the new values are any better. Failing that, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I think I actually had missed a character in the token (hence the format error) I generated new tokens anyway and now it is back to the original timed out exception..Edit:  I moved the verifyCredentials() to right above the twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(oathAccessToken); and I know get this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Authentication credentials are missing. See http://twitter4j.org/configuration.html for the detail.

Comment: The full exception is:xception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Authentication credentials are missing. See http://twitter4j.org/configuration.html for the detail.
 at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.ensureAuthorizationEnabled(TwitterBaseImpl.java:205)
 at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.fillInIDAndScreenName(TwitterBaseImpl.java:134)
 at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.verifyCredentials(TwitterImpl.java:1251)
 at login.Login.start(Login.java:26)
 at login.Login.main(Login.java:49)
Java Result: 1