# twitter4j configuration

Tags: java, api, properties, twitter4j

I'm trying to configure twitter4j to stream tweets

1. I got (consumer key/secret, access token & access secret) from  twitter already
2. I created a new java project and imported twiiter4j as a library

Now I want to know how to configure it ( http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html)

The first way :
Save a standard properties file named "twitter4j.properties". Place it to either the current directory, root of the classpath directory.

I'm using netbeans and want to know the file type I should choose when I create properties file and where exactly I have to place it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to your questions:

1. Select a normal text file type, add the contents and rename it to `twitter4j.properties`
2. You may place the file in the root folder of your project, or in any folder in the `classpath`. Just be sure the folder is in the `classpath`, thats what needs to be taken care of.

Comment: thanks . Done ,, now i want to run some examples, is there any guidelines on how to do so ? i tried but no results after a successful run !(new to java)

Comment: It's easy. I had tried some cool things, like updating status, changing profile picture, bio etc easily. http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/10/java-twitter-client-with-twitter4j.html is one cool and small tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

good day.

It's not a better way to use **twitter4j.properties** file in production for standalone application. 
because you need to guarantee that no one from users can not read your secret keys.

In this reason, better to use configuration factory class with hardcoded secret keys and make configuration on the flow.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example it is for normal Twitter object but same method works for TwitterStream as well. Basically, use ConfigurationBuilder [Twitter 4j with Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068976/twitter-4j-with-netbeans).

Answer (score 0):

Refer following code:

```
//Configuration for twitter4j
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
  .setOAuthConsumerKey("*********************")
  .setOAuthConsumerSecret("******************************************")
  .setOAuthAccessToken("**************************************************")
  .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("******************************************");

//Example for fetching public tweets 
//Sample which gives all tweets of Kim Kardarshian

    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
    int pageno = 1;
    String user = "@KimKardashian";
    List<Status> statuses = new ArrayList<Status>();

    while (true) {
      try {
        int size = statuses.size(); 
        Paging page = new Paging(pageno++, 100);
        statuses.addAll(twitter.getUserTimeline(user, page));
        if (statuses.size() == size)
          break;
      }
      catch(TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

//sample which gives "n" (here 10) tweets of particular user
        try{
         Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
         Paging p = new Paging();
          p.setCount(10);
         statuses.addAll(twitter.getUserTimeline("user",p));
       }catch(Exception e)
      { e.printStackTrace(); }
        for (Status st:statuses) {
            System.out.println(st.getText());
        }
```